# How do we design images/graphics that look hand drawn?

Tags: image

I wish to make the images that look more hand drawn. so please suggest me a software or source where we can draw such graphics, of course hand drawn!

As an example you can visit this page:

https://www.zomato.com/about

Answer (score 0):

If you want hand-drawn graphs, use the [XKCD style](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/jakevdp.github.com/downloads/notebooks/XKCD_plots.ipynb).

The examples you gave don't look like something you would describe as "hand-drawn", they have clean shapes and straight lines. Use a vector graphic tool for this, e.g. Inkscape.

Comment: This is totally not even a programming question, and is so far off topic, it should not be dignified with an answer. :)

Comment: Maybe someone moves it to http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ and then it is totally fine again :-)

Comment: @PhilLab, How to move a question to another section? Okay it should not have been here!

Comment: We can't migrate stuff there. The question author will have to do that himself. :)